# install opencv on raspberry Pi 3 and create Mat vector in opencv in linux

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, linux, debian, opencv

I am writing a code for object detection and coordination finding in OpenCV. In windows, everything is done and the program is working wit no problem, but I need to move it to Linux and run OpenCV in Raspberry pi 3 and Linux Debian platform. I have tried many ways to install the OpenCV on Raspberry Pi and after long hours spending, I was not successful in loading te #inlcude files of OpenCV to use and also I cannot even define a "Mat" for loading an image.

I appreciate any help or tip to solve this issue.

Thanks

Mehdi

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the OpenCV development packages from the repository (usually suffixed with `-dev` )? Without knowing the specific components of OpenCV you are using, version or programming language, I am assuming you want to use the most common header files. You may need to include others depending on your requirements but the following is a basic guide.

From the terminal install the header files with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcv-dev libhighgui-dev
```

The current version in the repositories is 2.4. If using C++, the header files are included as an example:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

In your code use the namespace `using namespace cv;` or prefix OpenCV objects with `cv::` as in `cv::Mat image;` or `cv::Point point;`.

Again in C++ don't forget to add the following, usually at the end of your compile statement:

```
`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

For example:

```
$ g++ test_opencv.cpp -o test_opencv `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: How is your experience with the debian opencv package? I did build openCV 3.2 with cmake and neon optimization and believe this is the way to go, although it's some work to get all the prerequisites.